# border wxpython color

Tags: python, wxpython

I begin with Python programming and I need some help!

Actually I'm working on a graphical application using wxpython and I would like to be able to change dynamically the size & color of the border of any widgets like a "TextCtrl", a "Panel" and a "ListBox".

Have you any ideas about this ?

Thanks

Comment: On some platforms there are often no borders at all - I would go careful about this. If you REALLY need this, you can try to manually draw a rectangle using a `wx.PaintDC` at `wx.EVT_PAINT`.

Comment: I'm only working on Windows.I was able to set a raisen border on one of my widget and I would have hoped that it was also possible to change the color. I will try with wx.PaintDC at wx.EVT_PAINT. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the Widget Inspection Tool (http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool). It has a highlight function that basically does what you need. The wxPython demo has it in the Help menu, but you can add it to your own code. Just check out the instructions in the link above.

Comment: This evening, I will take a look on this. Thanks Mike D.

Comment: Thanks to you I have found out the wxPython script demo. Very useful! Thanks.BBye